Local variables performance vs global in example
I study performance of C code. OS is Windows 10.
Suddenly I found that the same code runs 2x faster if I use local variables against the same code with global variables.
I can't understand why. Tested both in Visual Studio and GCC. Same performance difference.
The test results:
fun_b
4254600908
Duration:  5.168000 sec
fun_a
4254600908
Duration:  18.455000 sec

The sample code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
unsigned int result;
unsigned int mask;
unsigned int i;
unsigned int fun_a(unsigned int value)
{
    result = 0;
    mask = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        if (value & mask) result++;
        mask <<= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
unsigned int fun_b(unsigned int value)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    unsigned int mask = 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        if (value & mask) result++;
        mask <<= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int N = 0x12345678;
    clock_t startClock, finishClock;
    double f;
    unsigned int A;
    
    ////////////////////////////////
    printf("fun_b\n");
    startClock = clock();
    A = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        A += fun_b(i);
    }
    finishClock = clock();
    printf("%u\n", A);
    f = (double)(finishClock - startClock) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("Duration:  %f sec\n", f);

    ////////////////////////////////
    printf("fun_a\n");
    startClock = clock();
    A = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        A += fun_a(i);
    }
    finishClock = clock();
    printf("%u\n", A);
    f = (double)(finishClock - startClock) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("Duration:  %f sec\n", f);
}

I expected fun_a and fun_b should take the same time to execute and I can't understand why fun_b runs twice as fast.

Note: on gcc you can reduce the function to just return __builtin_popcount(value); which is even faster.

Perhaps compilers can better optimize local variables (keep them in the CPU, reduce their use, whatever) because doing so won't screw up other code that needs them. Just an idea; IDK if it's right.

optimizing with loop unrolling can get completely rid of local mask and i. With global variables, they must at least have their final values after fun_a() has completed

Fun fact. I build the code with Clang. And both fun_a and fun_b runs equally fast.

When you look at the disassembly (gcc, -O3):
fun_b(unsigned int):
        mov     edx, 32
        mov     eax, 1
        xor     ecx, ecx
.L15:
        mov     esi, edi
        and     esi, eax
        cmp     esi, 1
        sbb     ecx, -1
        add     eax, eax
        sub     edx, 1
        jne     .L15
        mov     eax, ecx
        ret

fun_b just does stuff with registers. This is reasonably fast.
fun_a has to also populate the global variables with the right values because they are part of the function's observable side effects.
fun_a(unsigned int):
        mov     eax, 32
        xor     esi, esi
        xor     ecx, ecx
        mov     edx, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR result[rip], 0
.L3:
        test    edx, edi
        je      .L2
        add     ecx, 1
        mov     esi, 1
.L2:
        add     edx, edx
        sub     eax, 1
        jne     .L3
        mov     DWORD PTR mask[rip], edx
        mov     DWORD PTR i[rip], 32
        test    sil, sil
        je      .L1
        mov     DWORD PTR result[rip], ecx
        mov     eax, ecx
.L1:
        ret

which is that much slower for a small function like this. Note: it's only doing the final values, you will not be able to observe i and mask changing during the loop. And it's still that much of a difference.
Note: actually it is slightly more complicated as the compiler has inlined the functions and is considering the entire sum at once. Having to compute the values for the global variables has prevented it from optimizing it as well as it could.
If you want to benchmark the functions themselves, you would have to prevent inlining by e.g. calling them through function pointers like this: https://godbolt.org/z/v58bqveTc -- then the above explanation applies and the difference becomes even greater somehow.

You were more in the right direction than my initial answer was.

By feeding it to "Compiler Explorer" with gcc and full optimizations:
https://godbolt.org/z/vhcWT1zfv
As it turns out, gcc refuses to optimize the access to the global variables, whereas it does, of course, optimize the bejeezus out of the local variables. I am actually surprised it is only twice as fast. (I suppose multi-level CPU cache is to thank for that.)

EDIT
The above explanation was not exactly right, and I do not really deserve the 3 upvotes it has gathered. (But maybe what follows does.)
What seems to be happening is different, and it is very interesting. Thanks to user teapot418 who expressed his thoughts in his answer, which led me to have a closer look at it.
The gcc compiler has, in fact, largely optimized the global variables, too. As user teapot418 wrote, the code only reads the global variables once before the loop, and writes them back once after the loop. However, since the compiler had to store the updated values in the global variables at the end of the loop, it could not optimize the loop so well, and this results in the observed performance difference.
Specifically, in the case of fun_b (with the local variables) the compiler only needed to compute and return a final result. In other words, i did not have to hold the value 32 at the end of the loop, nor did mask have to contain the value 1 << 32. The compiler made use of these facts to produce a loop which is very optimal, containing only one jump instruction.
In the case of fun_b (with the global variables) the compiler had to make sure that even though the variables are being manipulated in registers, they are still being properly calculated, so as to be able to store the registers back into the global variables at the end of the loop. Thus, it was not able to optimize the loop so well, and as a result the loop contains not just one, but two jump instructions.
This explanation is also more in line with the observed difference in performance, which is only twice as slow.  If the code was accessing the global variables in each iteration, I would have expected it to be many more times slower.

What do we learn from this?
What we have known all along:
Do not. use. global. variables.
(That was just humor. The reasons to never use global variables have nothing to do with performance. You should not use them even if they were somehow faster.)
